# React Native how to programmatically navigate to a stack screen that is on a tab navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have searched tirelessly for an answer to this issue.

I have a Tab Navigator:

```
const AppNavigator = () => {
return (
<Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Search">
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Home"
    children={() => <HomeScreen />}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Search"
    children={() => <SearchContainerNavigator />}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
        <FontAwesome5 name="search" color={color} size={size} />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Feedback"
    children={() => <FeedbackScreen />}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="email" color={color} size={size} />
      ),
    }}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>
);
};
```

And this Stack navigator:

```
const SearchContainerNavigator = () => (
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false}} initialRouteName="SearchSelect">
    <Stack.Screen name="SearchSelect" component={SearchSelectScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="AircraftSearch" component={AircraftSearchScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="AircraftResults" component={AircraftResultsScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="AircraftDetail" component={AircraftDetailScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="BrandSearch" component={BrandSearchScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="BrandResults" component={BrandResultsScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="BrandDetail" component={BrandDetailScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Favourites" component={FavouritesScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
)
```

My issue is how do I programmatically navigate from HomeScreen tab to the AircraftDetailsScreen on the Search Tab??

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
HomeScreen is a class.

 handleAircraftSelect = (aircraft_id) => {
 this.props.navigation.navigate("Search", {
   screen: "AircraftDetail",
   params: { id: aircraft_id },
 });
 };
```

Answer (score 7):

```
navigation.navigate('Search', {screen: 'AircraftDetail'});
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator

Comment: In my HomeScreen on a button press event i call that code. But I get a undefined 'navigation' error?

Comment: yeah sorry i've mistaken screen name and component name (i usually keep both the same to avoid mistakes), edited my answer, try again please

Comment: As i say this.props.navigation is giving undefined error. How do I get reference to the the navigation prop?

Comment: post the code snippet where you are calling navigation.navigate(), else we don`t know much.... or as best, post a whole screen

Comment: do you have a constructor in the class like this?

constructor(props) {

super(props)

}

Comment: Yes I have.It is not recognizing navigation object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231369/discussion-between-vaclav-ryska-and-user8717499).

Answer (score 2):

For react-navigation 6.x you can use this like below:

```
navigation.jumpTo('Profile', { name: 'Michaś' });
```